# How to draw line chart from Two variables in two different MySQL tables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I am new in php and learing how to draw Line chart for two different Temperature values in two different tables in MySQL. I can fetch the data from one table and draw it in a chart but I couldn't figured it out how to fetch the two temprature values from two different tables.

First table1:
id  temp
1    20

Second Table2:
id   temp
1     25

data.php code:

```
<?php 
 $servername = "localhost";
 $database = "test";
 $username = "test";
 $password = "12345";

 $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
 if (!$connect) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

$query = ("SELECT * FROM Table1 UNION SELECT * FROM Table2");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array(); 

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

 array_push($data, [$row['time'], floatval($row['temp']), $row['time'], floatval($row['temp'])]); 
 }
 }
  echo json_encode($data);
  mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

the JS code :

```
setInterval(function () {

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

  function drawLineColors() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
   
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature2');
   

var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "data.php",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
    }).responseText;
    
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);

data.addRows(obj);

let rowIndex = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; //gets the row index of last row
let lastTime = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0); //gets the first column
let lastTemp = data.getValue(rowIndex, 1); //gets second column

let rowIndex2 = data.getNumberOfRows() - 1; //gets the row index of last row
let lastTime2 = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0); //gets the first column
let lastTemp2 = data.getValue(rowIndex,1); //gets third column

console.log(` ${lastTemp}, ${lastTemp2}`);
 
    $(".TempStatus").html(lastTemp + " &deg;C");
    $(".Temp2Status").html(lastTemp2 + " &deg;C");

   var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Sensors Scale'
    },
    colors: ['#a52714', '#097138']
  };
  var chart = new  google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
   }
    }, 5000);
```

How can I fetch the two temperature values from two tables?

Comment: Don't know if this is the only or best solution. But could always perform 2 separate queries on the tables

Comment: Any help for this :)

Comment: I tried it but did not work with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, let's query both tables separately.
then combine the data for the response, `Table1` & `Table2`...

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $database = "test";
  $username = "test";
  $password = "12345";

  $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
  if (!$connect) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $data = array(
    'Table1' => array(),
    'Table2' => array()
  );

  $query = ("SELECT * FROM Table1");
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      array_push($data['Table1'], [$row['time'], floatval($row['temp'])]);
    }
  }

  $query = ("SELECT * FROM Table2");
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      array_push($data['Table2'], [$row['time'], floatval($row['temp'])]);
    }
  }

  echo json_encode($data);
  mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

---

when drawing the chart, we can only have one x-axis.
so we will need to join the two tables on the time column.

but first, google charts only needs to be loaded once.
not every time we draw the chart.
so we'll load google charts first, before anything else.

and we don't know exactly how long it will take to get the data and draw the chart.
instead of using `setInterval`, we'll use `setTimeout` after the first draw has finished.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Sensors Scale'
    },
    colors: ['#a52714', '#097138']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    setTimeout(drawLineColors, 5000);
  });

  drawLineColors();

  function drawLineColors() {
    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data1.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data1.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');

    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data2.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function (jsonData) {
      data1.addRows(jsonData.Table1);
      data2.addRows(jsonData.Table2);

      var joinData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

      var rowIndex = data1.getNumberOfRows() - 1;
      var lastTime = data1.getValue(rowIndex, 0);
      var lastTemp = data1.getValue(rowIndex, 1);
      var rowIndex2 = data2.getNumberOfRows() - 1;
      var lastTime2 = data2.getValue(rowIndex2, 0);
      var lastTemp2 = data2.getValue(rowIndex2, 1);
      $(".TempStatus").html(lastTemp + " &deg;C");
      $(".Temp2Status").html(lastTemp2 + " &deg;C");

      chart.draw(joinData, options);
    });
  }
});
```

other notes...

1. `async: false` on ajax has been deprecated, use the `done` callback instead.
2. don't need the `'line'` package in google charts, it is for *material* line charts.
   you're using a *classic* line chart --> `google.visualization.LineChart`
   *material* --> `google.charts.Line`
   as well, don't need to convert the options for a classic chart,
   removed --> `google.charts.Line.convertOptions`

Comment: Thank you man for a nice solution and for your advises ..really appreciated. :)

Comment: there is a problem for output of php file: ``` Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/data2.php on line 22```

Comment: it says here `array_push($data` should be array.